# Port Forwarding on website

Tags: web, portforwarding

I'm noob in this field, so please help me understand this:
I have my web application launched on port 8080. I thought that if i forward port 8080 and enter from web browser: myexternalipadress:8080/Index.html it should open my website. please tell me why i'm wrong

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, hosting a website from your house is a fun thing indeed. In my experience, here is how I approach trouble shooting.

1.Making sure your server is configured properly.

- Launch the server application
- If your client and server are the same machine, make sure you can reach the server on localhost
- Access the server from a different computer on your LAN, use your servers lan ip. 192.168.?.?:8080
- If you can't get to it from another machine on your LAN, you may have firewall issues on the server

2.Making sure your network is configured properly

- This is where port forwarding comes into play. Figure out the LAN ip of the server and log into the router.
- Tell your router to forward the port (8080 in this case) to the server LAN ip address.
- Test it by telling your friend to access your server on (WAN_IP:8080 in web browser)

Comment: thanks once more, I'll try it from another computer in the lan and then from computer outside local network tommorow and tell you if it succeeds